# Rails: Custom URL For Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, blogs

In my rails app, I have a posts section to allow user submitted content. By default, the convention for URL's for new posts will be something like `yoursite/posts/8`. I am wondering if anyone knows if it is possible for there to be a method for users to create a custom URL route for this, such as making a new post and then having a string with "custom URL" so it becomes something like `'yoursite/posttopic'.` Does anyone know how one might go about doing this? Thank you!

Post schema looks like this:

```
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: You are probably looking for the [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem. Updated example from its [Quick start guide](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#rails-quickstart):

```
# edit app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
end

Post.create! title: "posttopic"

# Change Post.find to Post.friendly.find in your controller
Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
rails server
```

Now you can use this:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/posts/posttopic
```

Comment: Is there any way to take out the /posts part? and just make it /3000/customURL

Comment: Sure, in your `routes.rb` have this: `resources :posts, path: '/'`.

Comment: Hi, friendly_Id was exactly what I needed. Thank you!